# how to calculate a maximum difference in a vector

Tags: r

I want to calculate the maximum difference in the vector x

```
> x <- c(3,10,17,23,33,50,80,13,100,150)
> maxdiff <- 0
> for(i in 1:length(x)) {
+   if(x[i+1]-x[i] > maxdiff)
+   maxdiff <- x[i+1]-x[i]
+   
+ }
Error in if (x[i + 1] - x[i] > maxdiff) maxdiff <- x[i + 1] - x[i] : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
> print(maxdiff)
[1] 6
```

Comment: will `max(diff(x))` suffice?

Comment: Common `for` loop typo: you want `for(i in 1:length(x))` or `for(i in seq_along(x))`, not `for(i in x)`

Comment: `minMax <- function(Vector){
  return (abs(max(Vector)-min(Vector)))
}`
minMax(x)

Comment: Also, think what happens for the first and last values of `i`. If `i` is the same as `length(x)` then `x[i + 1]` doesn't exist, leading to your error. You might want `for(i in 1:(length(x) - 1)`...

Comment: Is the expected answer 87?

Comment: @M.Viking  yes it is.

Comment: Good. Both Wimpel comment and Gregor Thomas second comment return 87.

Comment: Are you sure @Wimpel ' suggestion is not enough?

Comment: yes you are right;

Comment: @Gregor Thomas
can you explain why: for(i in 1:(length(x) - 1). I want more detail

Comment: There are 10 elements in `x`, on the final iteration of the original `for` loop, the code asks for `x[i+1]`, a non-existent 11th element, this results in the error message

Comment: @M.Viking  you mean we reduce the 1 that we add it in the code x[i+1], because when the loop reach  the 10th element it will add one x[10+1] which id doesn't exist in the vector. right??

Answer (score -1):

```
> x <- c(3,10,17,23,33,50,80,13,100,150)
> maxdiff <- 0
> for(i in 1:(length(x) - 1)) {
+   if(x[i+1]-x[i] > maxdiff)
+   maxdiff <- x[i+1]-x[i]
+   
+ }
> print(maxdiff)
[1] 87
```

Comment: This doesn't work generically. The maximum difference could be negative.

Comment: @socialscientist any other suggestion  or more clarification.

Comment: Please read the comments on your post, which seemed to address your question. You indicated the suggested solution did not work, but did not explain why even though the solution should generally work unlike the above.